# Running a test using pytest-xdist is opening several tabs

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, pytest-xdist

I have 3 tests as shown in the code below to run in parallel using pytest-xdist.

```html
from time import sleep

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions

port = 4444
command_executor = 'http://127.0.0.1:%s/wd/hub' % port
options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required')
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')


def test_a():
    driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor=command_executor,
        options=options
    )
    driver.get('https://www.amazon.com/')
    sleep(10)


def test_b():
    driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor=command_executor,
        options=options
    )
    driver.get('https://google.com')
    sleep(10)


def test_c():
    driver = webdriver.Remote(
        command_executor=command_executor,
        options=options
    )
    driver.get('https://facebook.com/')
    sleep(10)
```

Ran the following command from command prompt.

```html
 py.test -n 3 tests/tests
```

I expected 3 chrome instances to be launched one for each test. But, a chrome instance is launched with 3 tabs. Only the 1st tab seems to be doing the navigation and 2nd and 3rd tabs are just empty tabs. Please see screenshot below. How do I get it to launch 3 chrome instances?

[image]

Python version: Python 3.11.4 (latest stable version)
I am on the latest xdist version: pytest-xdist 3.3.1
I am running this on local selenium server launched using:

```
java -jar selenium-server-4.10.0.jar standalone
```

selenium server is also the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase) to simplify running tests on a grid. After `pip install -U seleniumbase` and then starting up a grid, you can run `pytest -n 3 --server=127.0.0.1` on the following script. There's a special part added at the top to automatically call `pytest` with those args if calling `python` directly:

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from pytest import main
    main([__file__, "-n 3", "--server=127.0.0.1"])


class MyTestClass(BaseCase):
    def test_1(self):
        self.driver.get("https://google.com")
        self.sleep(2)

    def test_2(self):
        self.driver.get("https://facebook.com")
        self.sleep(2)

    def test_3(self):
        self.driver.get("https://seleniumbase.io")
        self.sleep(2)
```

If you don't want to use the grid, remove the `--server=127.0.0.1` part.